# Assign hash values after being declared

Tags: ruby

Lets say I declared a hash like

```
foo = { }
```

Under normal circumstance, if I need to add a new item to the hash, I would simply do

```
foo[:baz] = "mike"
foo[:quz] = "jake"
```

I was wondering whether it was possible to do the above using a block to avoid repetitive code.

### edit

assignment is more than 2, lets say 30+

Comment: I don't see any advantage with block against this style.. May be you need to clear yourself more..

Comment: you mean how to set multiple values at once?

Comment: perhaps not a block...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`Hash#merge!`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge!) to set multiple values at once:

```
foo = {}

# later ...

foo.merge!({
  :baz => "mike",
  :quz => "jake"
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a new item to an Hash (or to be precise, to assign a value to as specific hash key) you use the following syntax

```
hash[key] = value
```

There is no more succinct way to do it and there would be no advantage of using a block in this context.

If you have multiple values, you can use merge

```
foo.merge({
  baz: "mike",
  quz: "jake",
})
```

or

```
foo.merge(baz: "mike", quz: "jake")
```

You can also compose the Hash from a different data set, for example

```
values = [:baz, "mike", :quz, "jake"]
foo.merge(Hash[values])
```

But the best solution probably depends on how you get the values that you want to add to the Hash.

Comment: thanks for the clarification!. Maybe `foo.merge!(baz: "mike", quz: "jake")` as it modifies the original object.